# What is difference between argThat and captureThat matchers in dart mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, mockito-dart

I've tried to find the difference here https://pub.dev/packages/mockito and using documentation to this matchers but didn't get it. Could someone provide example where I supposed to use captureThat rather than argThat?

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation for `argThat`](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/argThat.html) states:

> An argument matcher that matches an argument that matches `matcher`.

[The documentation for `captureThat`](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/captureThat.html) states:

> An argument matcher that matches an argument that matches `matcher`, and captures the argument for later access with `captured`.

Therefore the difference is that `captureThat` captures the matched argument for later examination whereas `argThat` does not.

See [Capturing arguments for further assertions](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito#capturing-arguments-for-further-assertions) from the Mockito documentation for examples for how to use captured arguments.

Comment: well I see, but still didn't get difference. I can do the same with argThat and without expect, right? like this `verify(cat.eatFood(argThat(contains("food"))));`

Comment: For that trivial example, sure, you can use `argThat` instead of `captureThat`.  For something more complex, you might prefer to check the captured value using some other mechanism than using a `Matcher`.  Or maybe you just want to inspect the captured value for debugging.